# keep on getting error that .float64 has no callable rint attribute

Tags: python, function, attributes, attributeerror

```
def solveNLEs(xyz0):
    def f(xyz):
        x=xyz[0]
        y=xyz[1]
        z=xyz[2]

        a=x**2 + y**2 - 10
        b=x*y + y*z**2 + 15
        c=y**2 + z - 25

        return np.array([a,b,c])

    xyz=fsolve(f,xyz0)
    x=xyz[0]
    y=xyz[1]
    z=xyz[2]
    return [x,y,z, f(xyz)]
print(np.round(solveNLEs(np.array([2,2,2])),5))
```

this is just meant to be a simple function to solve a set of non linear equations, it works however when I try to round the answer I come up with this error. I know I need to change the type of my answer but I'm not sure how to, trying to use dtype=float or .atype just throws up other errors

"loop of ufunc does not support argument 0 of type numpy.float64 which has no callable rint method" this is the exact error message that comes up

Comment: Where do you get the fsolve function from? scipy?

Comment: yes, left out the from scipy import fsolve at the start

Answer (score 2):

Seems to just be the rounding of an nested array which causes the problem. You could instead do the rounding inside the functions themselves on the individual elements.

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve
import numpy as np


def f(xyz):
    x = xyz[0]
    y = xyz[1]
    z = xyz[2]

    a = x**2 + y**2 - 10
    b = x*y + y*z**2 + 15
    c = y**2 + z - 25

    a = np.round(a, 5)
    b = np.round(b, 5)
    c = np.round(c, 5)

    return np.array([a, b, c])


def solve_nles(xyz0):
    xyz = fsolve(f, xyz0)
    x = xyz[0]
    y = xyz[1]
    z = xyz[2]

    x = np.round(x, 5)
    y = np.round(y, 5)
    z = np.round(z, 5)

    return [x, y, z, f(xyz)]

print(solve_nles(np.array([2, 2, 2])))
```

Note: You also don't need to create functions inside functions which use them, they are available to all methods after definiton.

Comment: Didn't realise that about functions thanks, did think it looked a bit strange. However, I can't just round the numbers inside the function as its a test code that rounds the answers. I just used the print function at the bottom to test if it would round. The test code for this function is 
```
answer = solveNLEs(np.array([2,2,2]))
print(np.round(answer,5))
```

Comment: But as I pointed out you cannot round a nested list (list with an array inside it). You will need to write an additional script to go through the elements in that list and round them individually e.g. `print([ np.round(elem, 2) for elem in answer ])`

Answer (score 1):

this was solved by

```
from scipy.optimize import fsolve

def solveNLEs(xyz0):
    def f(xyz):
        x=xyz[0]
        y=xyz[1]
        z=xyz[2]

        a=x**2 + y**2 - 10
        b=x*y + y*z**2 + 15
        c=y**2 + z - 25

        return np.array([a,b,c])

    xyz=fsolve(f,xyz0)
    x=xyz[0]
    y=xyz[1]
    z=xyz[2]
    return [np.array([x,y,z]), f(xyz)]
```

by changing the return value to an array in itself it was then able to work with the test code

```
answer = solveNLEs(np.array([2,2,2]))
print(np.round(answer,5))
```